# How to encrypt second data-disk (not system disk) to be automaticaly unlocked at boot?

Tags: encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I have already encrypted whole system disk following these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019 (
Whis way, I was able to encrypt /root and /boot partition and also /home partition (these a all on the first phisical disk). At a startup, I now have to enter an additional password.

What method/software should I use to fully encrypt an additional phisical disk I have to store documents? I would like this second disk to be automatically decripted when I login to Ubuntu. So I suppose programs like VeraCrypt would not be suitable.
I noticed programs like GnuPG, mCrypt, EncFS, eCryptfs. But I am totally lost.
Is there no option to encrypt such data disk on a system level?

I would be really gratefull for any link, suggestion.
Thank you! :)

So I have 2 hard drives:

1. SSD disk - it has 2 partitions: / and /home (both encrypted with cryptsetup - LUKS, so I have rootfs and /home partitions encrypted)
2. HDD disk - 1 partition for documents (this one I would like to be also encrypted and auto decrypted at login)

*I have found this method, which seems to be the same: https://davidyat.es/2015/04/03/encrypting-a-second-hard-drive-on-ubuntu-14-10-post-install/
Is this one optimal? First with gparted formating, than encrypting with LUKS cryptsetup...

Comment: Using LUKS and cryptsetup is the recommended way. I would not recommend automatic unlocking with a keyfile that is stored on the root filesystem, which kind of defeats the purpose, but I guess if the root filesystem is encrypted that would be acceptable. More useful information [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_a_non-root_file_system).

Comment: Thank you for an answer :) Why do you think it would not make sense? I mean the main reason for this secondary drive to be encrypted is so someone who gets phisical access to the computer cannot access files on this secondary drive. But I (and other users of Ubuntu) can, since these are our files... Am I missing something? Thank you :)

Comment: Sebastian, instructions from link were very helpful, but I found another much simpler method - but I do not know in which way it is different (apart for a last additional step to auto mount at startup). I went to DISKS - Format - Ext4 (+ I chose password protection with LUKS). I chose password and thats it. After next restart, I unlocked disk in Nautilus AND chose "remember password". So now it unlocks every time I log-in, but not when other users log-in. So in my opinion this is even more practical method, because it gives me option to not enable access to this disk to other users (Guest,...)

Comment: Regarding your first question, a keyfile is like a password, if you store it unencrypted, it's like you put your password in a file on your computer for anyone to read. Anyone with access to your computer (physical or not) has then access to the data you encrypt with it. That's why keyfiles should always be either on an encrypted drive protected by another password, or at least on a removable thumbdrive. Regarding your final solution, it protects your encrypted drive's password with your user password, so that works too.